# jquery ajax call on checkbox fails in ie, works fine in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer, checkbox

The following ajax call, made from a checkbox, somehow fails in Internet explorer, while it works in Firefox and Chrome.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="16086" id="16086" value="1" onclick="jQuery.ajax({type:'POST',dataType:'html',data:'checked=' + this.checked,success:function(data, textStatus){jQuery('#test_div').html(data);},url:'/tour/changeArticleAjax/article_id/16086'})" checked="checked">
```

*(copied from chrome's console)*

Checking the server access logs proves that IE does in fact make the call, so i concluded it must be a problem in the handling afterward. I have been looking for hours now, but i can't find the problem.

Probably not relevant: The ajax call in question is generated by the php framework symfony, using the jq_remote_function function.

Tested in:

```
IE 9 - Fails, 
IE 8, emulated by IE9 - Fails
IE 7, emulated by IE9 - Fails
Chrome 13.0.782.99 - Works
Firefox 5.0 - Works
```

Does anyone see whats wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check your `view sourse`. console is interpreted, so may not show something obvious.

Comment: I have done that now, both show identical code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havn't tested this.

Try renameing the ID to start with a letter:

> Naming rules:
>
> - Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z
> - Can be followed by: letters (A-Za-z), digits (0-9), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")
> - Values are case-sensitive

More info: [ID attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp)

Comment: That is indeed true. I have however just found that my problem is related to IE somehow not being bound to a session created by an earlier ajax call. The response of this call depends on that session. I'll accept your answer later on though, since it points out the flaw in the current syntax. Thanks.